# Special arrangement of subfigures

Tags: floats, positioning, subfloats

I need an image with five subfigures arranged this way.

[image]

I have tried to use subfig and floatrow, but I haven't been able to place the figures as I need them

Comment: I found the package \usepackage{textpos} really good for this. Then you would simply place your images in brackets like \begin{textblock}{1}(5.5,2.5){1,1} *Some figure* \end{textblock}. Read more about the package here
http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/textpos/textpos.pdf. Another method is using minipages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use a combination of `minipage`s and `subfigure` environments (from the [subcaption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package); a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{.33\textwidth}
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{name1}
    \caption{First subfigure}
    \label{fig:sub1}
  \end{subfigure}\\[1ex]
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{name2}
    \caption{Second subfigure}
    \label{fig:sub2}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.33\textwidth}
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{name3}
    \caption{Third subfigure}
    \label{fig:sub3}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.33\textwidth}
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{name4}
    \caption{Fourth subfigure}
    \label{fig:sub4}
  \end{subfigure}\\[1ex]
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{name5}
    \caption{Fifth subfigure}
    \label{fig:sub5}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Five subfigures}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used the `demo` option for the `graphicx` package to replace the actual figures with black rectangles and make my code compilable for everyone; do *not* use that option in your actual code.

Comment: Gonzalo, perhaps add [!htpb] after \begin{figure} ? Seems like quite a standard thing to do. This way we restrict the floating of the figure quite a bit. Using 4 images, the chances of the figure actually fitting is quite low. Also great solution =)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: thanks. As for the placement specifiers, for some time now, I've opted for not using them in my example codes unless the person asking the question explicitly mentions a problem with their use.

Answer (score 10):

You could use three `minipage`s next to each other:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\subcaptionbox{A}{\rule{3cm}{3.5cm}}\\[1ex]
\subcaptionbox{B}{\rule{3cm}{3.5cm}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\subcaptionbox{C}{\rule{3cm}{3.5cm}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\subcaptionbox{D}{\rule{3cm}{3.5cm}}\\[1ex]
\subcaptionbox{E}{\rule{3cm}{3.5cm}}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Pictures!}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could add `%` after the first and second `\end{minipage}` commands to prevent undesired blank spaces.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Good point, thanks! I've also adopted the `\\[1ex]` from your answer to get nicer vertical spacing.

Answer (score 6):

Using the [`subfig` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) you can use `tabular`s to arrange the images:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \subfloat[subfigure 1]{\rule{100pt}{50pt}} \\
    \subfloat[subfigure 2]{\rule{100pt}{50pt}}
  \end{tabular} \hfill
  \begin{tabular}[m]{c}
    \subfloat[subfigure 3]{\rule{100pt}{50pt}}
  \end{tabular} \hfill
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \subfloat[subfigure 4]{\rule{100pt}{50pt}} \\
    \subfloat[subfigure 5]{\rule{100pt}{50pt}}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{bla bla bla bla bla bla}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Vertical alignment across the subfigures is obtained using the optional `tabular` parameter `[m]` for `m`iddle. Using `\hfill` as suggested will push the columns of subfigures to the outer edges of the text block. If you want these columns evenly spaces, use `\null\hfill` on the left of the first column and `\hfill\null` on the right of the last column. Alternatively, a fixed spacing using `\hspace{<len>}` is also possible, where `<len>` is any recognized TeX length.

`tabular` column specification necessarily adds a little horizontal space of `\tabcolsep` between columns. If you want this removed (for whatever reason), you can use a `{@{}c@{}}` column specification instead of `{c}`.

Comment: Is this the preferred solution when using memoir?

Comment: @NeilG: You could probably use any of the solutions in the answers in terms of positioning. Although [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) provides its own `\subbottom` and `\subtop` sub-figure tools.

Comment: yes, so I figured I could use `\subbottom` inside a tabular?  Yours seems like the least verbose solution.

Comment: @NeilG: Yes. I've mocked something up (see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EW5Ih.png)) and it seems to work.

Comment: Awesome!!  Thank you.  This is exactly what I was looking for.