# LaTeX advanced use of subcaption package

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, subcaption

I am trying to create a figure with subfigures aligned both horizontally and vertically in the same figure to explain this better i attached a primitive drawing.

[image: desired image layout]

The labels are not of importance in which order they come i just cant seem to figure out how to place the (f) and (g) images on top of (d) and (e) in the same

`\begin{figure}`

`...`

`\end{figure}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Special arrangement of subfigures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35240/5764); [Placing Subfigures vertically](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66955/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to box each column up in a minipage, and provide a minipage for each subimage in the last column.  You can then include the `\subcaption` inside each of the minipages.  Here is an example following your layout, but just using text instead of the images:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\linewidth}
    \centering \large A

    \vspace{2cm}

    \large AA
    \subcaption{Subfigure A}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\linewidth}
    \centering \large B

    \vspace{2cm}

    \large BB
    \subcaption{Subfigure B}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\linewidth}
    \centering \large C

    \vspace{2cm}

    \large CC
    \subcaption{Subfigure C}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
      \centering F
     \subcaption{Subfigure F}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
      \centering D \subcaption{Subfigure D}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
      \centering G
     \subcaption{Subfigure G}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
      \centering E \subcaption{Subfigure E}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{Whole figure caption}
  \label{fig:cap}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]