# Not classical distribution of multiple images

Tags: graphics

I'm using the packages `\usepackage[font=small]{caption}`, `\usepackage{graphicx}` and `\usepackage[font=small, subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}` and I would like to organize 7 images like this:

[image: Desired distribution of pictures]

Is there a way to achieve it with these packages?

Comment: It's easier for us to help you when you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Please do this next time.

Comment: Related, perhaps duplicate(s): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23226/alignment-and-scaling-of-nested-subfigures http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43010/how-to-build-and-combine-sophisticated-layouts-in-figures http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66955/placing-subfigures-vertically/ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/latex-advanced-use-of-subcaption-package

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Indeed. A combination of all leads to my solution ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put two `subfigure` environments abreast and inside the second one you can work with the command `\subcaptionbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\mypicture[1][1cm]{\tikz\node[draw,rectangle, minimum width=#1,minimum height={2*#1},rounded corners]{};}

\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small, subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3333\linewidth}
    \centering\mypicture[2cm]
     \caption{}\label{fig:1a}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.6666\linewidth}
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:1b}}[.3333\linewidth]{\mypicture}\hfill%
    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:1c}}[.3333\linewidth]{\mypicture}\hfill%
    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:1d}}[.3333\linewidth]{\mypicture}

    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:1e}}[.3333\linewidth]{\mypicture}\hfill%
    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:1f}}[.3333\linewidth]{\mypicture}\hfill%
    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:1g}}[.3333\linewidth]{\mypicture}
  \end{subfigure}%
\end{figure}

\begin{verbatim}
\ref{fig:1a}\quad\ref{fig:1b}\quad
\ref{fig:1c}\quad\ref{fig:1d}\quad
\ref{fig:1e}\quad\ref{fig:1f}\quad\ref{fig:1g}
\end{verbatim}
\ref{fig:1a}\quad\ref{fig:1b}\quad
\ref{fig:1c}\quad\ref{fig:1d}\quad
\ref{fig:1e}\quad\ref{fig:1f}\quad\ref{fig:1g}
\end{document}
```

[image]