# Special arrangement of subfigures in memoir

Tags: positioning, memoir, subfloats

As described in answers to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35240/special-arrangement-of-subfigures/35243?noredirect=1#comment363076_35243), the following code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering%
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\begin{tabular}{c}%
\subbottom[A]{\rule{0.3\linewidth}{100pt}} \\
\subbottom[B]{\rule{0.3\linewidth}{100pt}}
\end{tabular}
&
\subbottom[C]{\rule{0.6\linewidth}{230pt}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{D}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Leads to significant misalignment.  How do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: tabular defaults to aligning by center, although you can select top (first baseline) or bottom (last baseline).  Images and rule align to the bottom.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I'm not sure I understand what happened, but thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Basically, the tabular on the left aligned its center to the bottom of the rule on the right.  In the answer below, the bottom of the tabular on the left aligned with the bottom or the rule on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `b` for the optional argument in the inner tabular:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering%
\begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{}}
\begin{tabular}[b]{c}%
\subbottom[A]{\rule{0.3\linewidth}{100pt}} \\
\subbottom[B]{\rule{0.3\linewidth}{100pt}}
\end{tabular}
&
\subbottom[C]{\rule{0.6\linewidth}{230pt}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{D}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd however, suggest `minipage`s of fixed height inside the `tabular` (again, with `b`ottom alignment):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering%
\begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{}}
\begin{minipage}[c][230pt][b]{0.3\linewidth}%
\subbottom[A]{\rule{\linewidth}{100pt}}\\[9.5pt]
\subbottom[B]{\rule{\linewidth}{100pt}}
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}[c][230pt][b]{0.6\linewidth}%
\subbottom[C]{\rule{\linewidth}{230pt}}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
\caption{D}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun.  For some reason, the first subbottom has a 5pt smaller top margin than all subsequent subbottoms.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newsubfloat{figure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path
(0,0) node(C){\subbottom[C]{\rule{0.6\linewidth}{230pt}}}
(C.north west) +(0,5pt) node[below left]
{\subbottom[A]{\rule{0.3\linewidth}{100pt}}}
(C.south west) node[above left]
{\subbottom[B]{\rule{0.3\linewidth}{100pt}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{D}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: figure]

Comment: Great general solution.  Did not know you could do this!

Comment: It's based on experiments I did while working on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150367/best-way-to-make-family-photo-album-in-latex/150481#150481